# Using Wolfram Alpha to output table of values over the integers

Tags: math-software, wolfram-alpha

I'm trying to get Wolfram Alpha to output a table of values over the integers for a given function, in example:

> n^2-n
>
> 1----1
>
> 4----2
>
> 9----3
>
> ...  ...

(using '-'s instead of whitespace to separate the columns)

Despite being a rather simple thing my searches for a command that does this turn up nothing. Does anyone know how I can get it to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about Mathematica commands? This is always the best first idea when using wolfram alpha.

`Table[n^2, {n,1,10}]`

for instance. If you want the table of the values of $n^2$ with $n$ between $1$ and $10$.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Comment: This is good, but how do I get it to display decimal values instead of fractions?

Answer (score 6):

Try [`Table[n^2, {n, 1, 5}]`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5Bn%5E2,%20%7Bn,%201,%205%7D%5D).

Answer (score 1):

To get the output exactly in the form you describe in the question, you should use

```
TableForm[Table[{n^2,n},{n,1,k}]]
```

For example:

[image]

EDIT: Well, it seems this only works in Mathematica proper. Oh well.